# How to add attrs to Widget at rendertime

Tags: django, django-templates, django-forms

I have the following form:

```
from django import forms    
class PostForm(forms.Form):
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

and the following part in my template

```
<p>{{ form.message }}</p>
```

it renders the field as a textarea as specified. Though for the template I want to set it to 4 rows and 25 cols without actually touching the form definiton. Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class PostForm(forms.Form):
     message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

    def set4x25(self):
        self.fields['message'].widget.attrs = {'rows':'4', 'cols': '25'}
```

And in template:

```
{{ form.set4x25 }}
{{ form.message }}
```

You can customize this idea as you like.

Comment: That's way too simple :D :D Thanks

Comment: This does touch the form definition, isn't it?

Comment: @Andrey Fedoseev I think Jokey means declaration of form's fields.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in template with [django-widget-tweaks](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-widget-tweaks):

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}
<p>{% render_field form.message rows="4" cols="25" %}</p>
```

or

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}
<p>{{ form.message|attr:"rows:4"|attr:"cols:25" }}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it from the template but you can:

1. Use CSS to specify the width and height of the textarea. This will override rows and cols attributes
2. Render the field manually:

   ```
     {% with form.message as field %}
     <textarea name="{{ field.html_name }}"
               id="{{ field.html_initial_id }}"
               rows="4" cols="25">{% if field.data %}{{ field.data }}{% endif %}</textarea>
     {% endfor %}
   ```